# Page links giving me errors on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've just started to learn ruby on rails but ran into some issues while linking pages together. The error occurred after I was trying to get localhost:3000 to be my home page instead localhost:3000/home/index

Instead of my site I got the error:

> undefined local variable or method `portal_pages_updates_path' for #<#:0x2d37ff8>

and highlighting my footer links as the issue.

```
  </small>
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li><%= link_to "Updates",portal_pages_updates_path  %></li>
     <li><%= link_to "Contact", portal_pages_contact_path %></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

This is my Routes.rb that I modified which game me the error

```
GameProject::Application.routes.draw do

root :to =>'home#index'
match '/contact', to:  'portal_pages#contact', via: 'get'
match '/updates', to:  'portal_pages#updates', via: 'get'
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error message?

Comment: I edit and put more info or do you want the Full Trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use named routes for custom action, you have to specify it in your routes.rb

```
match '/contact', to:  'portal_pages#contact', via: 'get', as: "portal_pages_contact"
match '/updates', to:  'portal_pages#updates', via: 'get', as: "portal_pages_updates"
```

Comment: I've gotten a SyntaxError "unexpected tASSOC"

Comment: @user3344900: I modified my answer. Hash syntax was wrong. Mixed up old and new